# How to get values from EditText Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have bunch of `EditText` fields and I am trying to get their values. But it is returning empty strings. Here is my code:

```
public class add_product_fragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_product, container, false);

        mName = view.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        productName = mName.getText().toString().trim();

        mPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        productPrice = mPrice.getText().toString().trim();

        mDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.productDescription);
        productDescription = mDescription.getText().toString().trim();

        mQuantity = view.findViewById(R.id.productQuantity);
        productQuantity = mQuantity.getText().toString().trim();

        addToInventory = view.findViewById(R.id.addToInventoryBtn);

        addToInventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println(productName + ", " + productDescription + ", " + productType
                        + ", " + productPrice + ", " + productQuantity);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

It is not working because of `Fragment`s or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can interact with `Activity`'s/`Fragment`'s UI only after `onResume()` returns. So having something like `yourEditText.getText().toString()` in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` lifecycle method would unavoidably result in an empty string.

You should "retrieve" the `EditTexts'` values after the user interaction, meaning the `addToInventory`'s `onClick` listener should look as follows:

```
addToInventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println(
                mName.getText().toString().trim() + ", " +
                mDescription.getText().toString().trim() + ", " +
                mProductType.getText().toString().trim() + ", " +
                mPrice.getText().toString().trim() + ", " + 
                mQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
        }
    });
```